# Does a custom WordPress theme require updates to it's source code?

Tags: theme-development

I have not found a satisfactory answer to this question. WordPress releases a lot of updates. As I am relatively new to custom theme development, I do not know if some of the changes in the WordPress updates affect themes at all.

So, if you make a custom theme, would updates to WordPress need to be reflected in the custom theme?

Would I encounter problems if I never update my custom theme?

Comment: The only reason you'd *need* to update a WordPress theme due to a WordPress update would be if you depend on a WordPress function that is deprecated or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a custom WordPress theme may require updates to its source code over time. As WordPress core updates and evolves, there may be changes that affect the functionality or compatibility of the theme. Additionally, if the theme uses any third-party libraries or plugins, updates to those dependencies may also require changes to the theme's code.

Some common reasons a custom WordPress theme may require updates to its source code include:

Compatibility with WordPress core updates: WordPress regularly releases updates that add new features, fix bugs, and address security issues. Custom themes should be tested and updated as necessary to ensure compatibility with these updates.

Compatibility with plugins: Custom themes may use plugins to add functionality. Updates to these plugins may require changes to the theme's code to maintain compatibility.

Bug fixes and improvements: Over time, bugs may be discovered in the theme's code, or opportunities to improve its performance or user experience may be identified. These changes may require updates to the theme's source code.

Security updates: As with any software, security vulnerabilities may be discovered in a custom WordPress theme. Updates to address these vulnerabilities may require changes to the theme's code.

Overall, it's important to stay up-to-date with WordPress core updates, as well as any third-party libraries or plugins used in a custom theme, to ensure its ongoing compatibility, functionality, and security.

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for a well informed answer outlining all the major considerations and you have delivered!